# How do I solve this UnicodeDecodeError?

Tags: python, web-scraping, text, encoding

I was trying to make a prophecy bot that generates prophecies from rap and country lyrics, but I keep hitting an error on the generation. The specific error is below. I am pulling the lyrics from a couple thousand line text files divided by individual artist.

[image: Error I keep Getting]

The error appears about 80% of the time and with the same position for each artist. I have tried utf8, cp452, and just straight binary but none of them seem to work. I have pasted my code below.

```
import random
import linecache


artists = ["astronautalis","common","garth brooks","johnny cash","marty robbins","mf doom","nas","willie nelson"]


#def file_len(fname):
 #   with open(fname) as f:
  #      for i, l in enumerate(f):
   #         pass
    #return i + 1

def prophecy(futuresize):
    if futuresize == "Large":
        for x in range(8):
            print(x)
            randartist = artists[random.randint(0,7)]
            print(randartist)
            fiellen = 'lyrics/' + randartist + '.txt'
            print(fiellen)
            file = open('lyrics/' + randartist + '.txt', 'r', encoding='cp1252', errors='ignore')
            print(file)
            count = 0
            count = len(open(fiellen).readlines())
            line_to_read = random.randint(0,(count - 1))
            line = linecache.getline(fiellen, line_to_read)
            print(line)
            file.close()













prophecy("Large")
```

Here are the current files I am working with as well.

[Lyric Files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JTgJDuUyi1ULmfgHaT8gtuPRFdAaagQU/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks again for your help everyone!

Comment: its hard to say for sure but at a guess its trying to use windows cp1260 and it should be using utf8 (although its impossible to say without the actual binary data)

Comment: It's little information to help you, but you can use chardet lib to help determine the right encoding. https://pypi.org/project/chardet/

Comment: you're just using ```open(fiellen)``` without specifying the encoding.  Have you specified the encoding there?

Comment: @ewong You got it, it seems like it wasn't encoding properly in the second open statement, thanks!